# instances of "you", "youuu", or "u" (not case sensitive) with "your client"

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

How to replace words
places all instances of "you", "youuu", or "u" (not case sensitive) with "your client" (always lowercase).

Example

Input: "We have sent the deliverables to you."
Expected: "We have sent the deliverables to **your client**."

Input: "Our team is excited to finish this with you."
Expected: "Our team is excited to finish this with **your client**."

Input: "youtube"
Expected: "youtube"

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (target, payload) {
    let regex = new RegExp(target, 'g')
    return this.valueOf().replace(regex, payload)
};

const autocorrect = str => {
   var replace = 'your client'
//  const correction = {
//    "you": replace ,
//   "youuuu": replace,
//   "u": replace,

// };
//   Object.keys(correction).forEach((key) => {
//   str = str.replaceAll(key, correction[key]);
// });

// // var str = wordInString(text, ['you', 'youuuu','u'], replace); 
//   return str;
  
  var mapObj = {
      "you": replace ,
  "youuuu": replace,
  "u": replace,
};
   return replaceAll(str,mapObj)
};
```

**Error
expected 'Oyour clientr team is excited to finish this with your client.' to equal 'Our team is excited to finish this with your client.'**

Comment: would you please post up better debugging info?

Comment: i mentioned the string , which replace you to your client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```js
[ 'We have sent the deliverables to you.',
  'Our team is excited to finish this with youuu.',
  'I like youtube'
].forEach(str => {
  let result = str.replace(/\b(?:you|youuu|u)\b/gi, 'your client');
  console.log(str + ' =>\n' + result);
});
```

Output:

```
We have sent the deliverables to you. =>
We have sent the deliverables to your client.
Our team is excited to finish this with youuu. =>
Our team is excited to finish this with your client.
I like youtube =>
I like youtube
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\b` -- word boundary
- `(?:` -- non cature group start
- `you` -- literal text
- `|` -- logical OR
- `youuu` -- literal text
- `|` -- logical OR
- `u` -- literal text
- `)` -- non cature group end
- `\b` -- word boundary
- `/gi` -- flags for gloabl (match multiple times), and ignore case
- `

Comment: expected 'Look forward to meeting youuuuu' to equal 'Look forward to meeting your client'

Comment: How many `u`s? If 1+ use regex `/\b(?:you+|u)\b/gi` instead

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match all variations of repeating `u` chars preceded by `yo`

```
\b(?:u|you+)\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:u|you+)` Match either a single `u` or `you` `youu` `youuu` etc...
- `\b`  A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TqY5Cv/1).

If this can occur `uu` and you also want to replace that, you could shorten it to:

```
\b(?:yo)?u+\b
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3tlNHC/1).

```js
[
  'We have sent the deliverables to you.',
  'Our team is excited to finish this with youuu.',
  'I like youtube'
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.replace(/\b(?:u|you+)\b/g, 'your client'))
);
```